# CakePHP Facebook plugin error in HTTPS not in HTTP

Tags: facebook, http, plugins, https, cakephp-2.0

I have set up the facebook plugin like the instructions.

1. Downloaded package and installed in app/plugins/facebook
2. Created app/config/facebook.php with my app's id, key and secret numbers, based on the example config file
3. Included $helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook') in my app_controller.php
4. Echoed the $this->Facebook->html() function in my layout (replcing the default html tag)
5. Echoed the $this->Facebook->init() function at the bottom of the layout, before

I run this code:

```
echo $this->Facebook->share('link');
```

If I go to: http://myhomepage.com it works but if I go to the same with HTTPS I just get a text share. In IE 10 and Chrome I get a `Not safe content error`. If I accept it it works.

How do I run it over SSL? I have bought the certificate, so it is valid and not a home-made self-signed one. I am running Cake PHP version 2.

I have tried to search the web, but I just find problems with the login function and not with the share button.

Comment: Hi! I manage to solve it. Maybe not the best solution, but it works for the moment.
First I edit FacebookHelper line 22:
public $__fbShareScript = 'https://myhomepage.com/FB.Share.php';
Then i created on file: myhomepage.com/FB.Share.php
<?php
$handle = @fopen("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>

Comment: If I look into the sourcecode. I now get:
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php" share_url="http://www.example.com/url_to_share" type="button" name="fb_share">share</a><script type="text/javascript" src="https://myhomepage.com/FB.Share.php"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below links for reference.

1. http://www.afbtemplates.com/tutorials/common-problems-facebook-secure-connections
2. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/
3. [Do I need to support ssl on my site that allows login through facebook connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477394/do-i-need-to-support-ssl-on-my-site-that-allows-login-through-facebook-connect)